# Set defaults traits for guide_colorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set up some defaults for `guide_colorbar` in ggplot2. In the same way that you can set a default theme, I'd like to be able to set default `barheight`, `frame.color`, etc. Right now I have to copy and paste the same `guide_colorbar()` for every ggplot object, which seems inefficient!

I'm fairly stumped by this one, I can't find any colorbar options in theme. I can set default legend traits such as legend height, but that will apply to all legends, not just colorbars. I've written my own `scale_color_me` function that has the attributes that I want, but ideally I'd like to change the defaults such that any colorbar rendered (e.g. by `scale_color_viridis`) has my updated defaults

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  sample_n(1000) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(price, carat, color = depth)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "fine")
```

[image]

```
diamonds %>%
  sample_n(1000) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(price, carat, color = depth)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient(
    low = "white",
    high = "tomato",
    guide = guide_colorbar(
      frame.colour = "black",
      barheight = 15,
      frame.linewidth = 2,
      ticks.colour = "black",
      ticks.linewidth = 2
    )
  ) +
  labs(title = "better")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Love how easy it is to customize the colorbar now with `guide_colorbar`, but that's a lot of code to copy and paste with every plot! Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it really that troublesome to define something like `gc = guide_colorbar(<your preferences>)` once in your code, & use `guide = gc` in whichever `scale_color_XXX()` you are using?

Comment: good idea, hadn't thought of that, thanks!